# I am looking for a vlookup of some sort to find averages prices.

Tags: excel

I am currently trying to find the following: i have 3 years of monthly stock prices and i want on a different excel sheet to put the average per year. So I have 2013,14,15 and 12 months of share prices. (total 36 lines) I want to have on separate sheets the yearly averages (2015,14,13) thus only 3 lines. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: use AVERAGEIFS()

Comment: Better to post sample data. In which format data is stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `OFFSET`/`MATCH` and `AVERAGE`. Since you only have 3 years for which you want to get averages of the monthly values, I am using a simplifyied `OFFSET` formula:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$1:$M$1,MATCH(Sheet2!$A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)-1,))
```

I will assume that Sheet1 holds stock names in column A, and monthly sock prices prices beginning in columns B (for Jan 2013):

[image: see here].

In Sheet2 I have identified 2 stocks that I want to get average annual price for. within the `OFFSET` formula, set the first range begin and end with the cells directly above your data set (in the header), spanning columns included in your given year. The `-1` is there because `MATCH` will return the row in which a stock sits, and we want to *offset* the average range by one less than the row number. You can see below for an example of how I would modify the formula to return average monthly stock price for 2014.

[image]

Comment: thank you Benjamin, it was very helpful! much appreciated!